# How to catch up an event in angular-meteor when a user logged in, logged out or the user changes?

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor

In meteor-angular, I want to catch up new user login, logout changes in one component. I tried to subscribe userData in the component's init, it is not detecting change is user login/logout events. If i refresh tha page, it is detecting user details. Is anything can be used in component when login/logout/ another user events? Its purpose is to recalculate user roles for different user at the component and roles will change according to different users and want to catch it in client's component. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The accounts package provide onLogin and onLogout event that you can put into your component to catch a change of user.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin

I would suggest putting this in your main app component but I suppose it could be used from any component.

The only other suggestion may be looking at tracker.autorun around your user data subscription.